# iPhone 6+ images

Tags: ios, iphone, image, hig

I have a question that I need confirmation on. I know that the Apple Developer document shows App icon size at @3x
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html.
Does this also apply to regular images that you use in your App? I just need to make 100 percent sure. The other stackoverflow answers I encountered just show App icon sizes, but doesn't address regular images that you use through out your App.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your app to take full advantage of the Retina HD display then yes, you need to have all versions for all images used by your app, i.e. image.png, image@2x.png, image@3x.png.

Dont forget to setup launch screens for each iPhone size, or your bigger phones will just enlarge your app views without really using AutoLayout or using the high def images.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't apply for regular images that you use in you app. Make sure they are with good pixels.
Provide high-resolution (@2x) versions of all image assets.
Images that are not @2x will appear blurry on the Retina display.

source:
      https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/